# Inequality about holomorphic functions on the disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that $ |g(z) +g(-z)| \leq 2|z|^{2}, z\in \mathbb{D}, g:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow\mathbb{D}, g(0)=0$

I applied Schwarz's lemma and got $|g(z)| \leq |z|$ and $g(-z)\leq |-z|=|z|$.

$$|g(z)+g(-z) | \leq |g(z)| +|g(-z)| \leq 2|z|$$

the first inequality follows from the triangle inequality. But, I'm now stuck as I cannot just say that $2|z|\leq 2|z|^2$ since $z\in \mathbb{D}$ where it it is not true. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(z)=\frac{g(z)+g(-z)}{2}$; we notice that $h(z)=h(-z)$ which means (as the Taylor series of $h$ has only even powers) that $h(z)=u(z^2)$ for some holomorphic function $u: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D , u(0)=0$ as clearly $h$ satisfies same conditions too by the properties of $g$.

Applying Schwarz lemma to $u$ we get $|u(z)| \le |z|$ or $|h(z)| =|u(z^2)| \le |z|^2$ and that is precisely what we need to prove